# Requests Session with Stem Not Closed Correctly, Tor No Longer Restarting

Tags: python, tor, stem

I built a program that runs a `requests` session in a separate thread, using `stem` sub-modules to update the control port. On an initial install and with the manual addition of the following parameters to the `torrc` file, things worked fine:

```
ControlPort 9151 
HashedControlPassword 16:"HASHED PASSWORD"
CookieAuthentication 1
```

Unfortunately, I neglected to enclose the session in a `try/except`, so my thread halted with an error, but didn't run `session.close()`. Since then, Tor has thrown an error prompt unless I remove the `torrc` file edits. So, I suspect that the session has not detached itself from the 9150 and 9151 proxies, but I have no clue how to detach it. Process Explorer doesn't show Tor or Firefox running in any location, so it's not as straightforward as a fix when I make the same mistake with `selenium` sessions. The program is running on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that `Controller` and `Signal` in `stem` will update the ControlPort without the edits to the `torrc` file. I'll need to investigate further to understand why.